# Initialization of a static variable: position dependent?

Tags: c++, oop

I have the following files:

H file

```
class myclass
{
   static int variable;

   // constructor
   myclass();
}
```

Cpp file

```
// initialize this variable
int myclass::variable = 0;

myclass::myclass()
{
   // I use here the static variable
}
```

My question is: when is the static variable going to be initialized? First or after the constructor?

What if I put the

```
int myclass::variable = 0;
```

line after the class constructor definition? Will it still be initialized before a class' object is instantiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static like this will be initialised when the application starts up, which I assume will be way before you instantiate "myclass".

Basically it doesn't matter where you define it due to this.

However, if you create a global copy of "myclass" then I believe you can get into issues.  It would be perfectly legal to put the definition before the variable initialisation e.g.

```
myclass globalInstance;
int myclass::variable = 0;
```

In the above case I'm pretty sure that myclass's constructor will be called before variable is initialised.  In such a case it would be best to define myclass after variable.

Edit: See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html

Comment: small correction: it _can_ matter where the variable is defined, the compilers may reorder the initializations if the variable is moved. however, one must not rely on the order, the only guarantee is that the static variables will be initialized before main()

Comment: `myclass::variable` will still be zero initialized before the constructor call for `globalInstance` as the latter is dynamic initialization.

Comment: @Vlad: Objects with static storage duration at namespace scope in a translation unit must be initialized in the order in which they are declared so the compiler _must_ reorder the initializations if you reorder the declarations (unless, under the "as if" rule, it can determine that the order doesn't matter).

Comment: @Charles: is the order _within_ a single translation unit guaranteed by the standard? (I didn't know that.)

Comment: @Vlad: In general, yes. There are some exceptions such as static members of non-explicitly specialized class templates.